# How to linearize a $1$-norm equality constraint?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be fixed vectors of $1$-norm $C$. My optimization problem is the following

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{\beta \in \Bbb{R}^n}{\text{minimize}} & | \beta |_M \\ \text{subject to} & | x + \beta |_1 = C\\ & |x + \beta - y|_1 \leq D\end{array}$$

where $M \in \{ 1, 2, \infty \}$. I can choose it to be $M=2$ and my problem can easily become with quadratic target function. I Also can easily 'linearize' the $|x + \beta - y|_1 \leq D$ condition, but I find it hard to linearize $ |x+\beta|_1 = C$. One can make it
$$
|x+\beta|_1 \leq C
\\
|x+\beta|_1 \geq C
$$
but again, I can't figure how to linearize the second one, $|x+\beta|_1 \geq C$.

Comment: This constraint is not convex. You need to add binary variables that can model a piecewise nonlinear function, see section 7.6 in [this document](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3_OM.pdf)

Comment: I made a little mistake. My vectors $x,y$ are of $l_1$ norm $C$. This would immediately yield the $\beta = 0^n$ for most cases for $C$ and $D$ and I don't want it. In my case I can't relax.

Comment: Substitute non linear constraint for equivalent set of linear inequalities and/or equalities.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2291301/339790).