# Calculate distance from a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the norm $\ell_1$ unit ball

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given the ball of center $0$, radius $1$ in norm $\ell_1$

$$B(0,1) := \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \Vert x \Vert_1 \le 1 \right\}.$$

calculate the distance $d_B(x)$ from a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to $B(0,1)$, where $d_B(x)$ defined by

$$d_{B}(x) := \inf\left\{\Vert x-c \Vert_2: c \in B(0,1) \right\}, \quad  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

---

**My attempt**

I considered two cases

1. If $x \in B(0,1)$ then $d_B(x)=0$.
2. If $x \notin B(0,1)$. I have tried to use many inequality to find the minimum point of this distance but I still can't find it.

Comment: [Duchi et al. 2008](https://stanford.edu/~jduchi/projects/DuchiShSiCh08.pdf) describes an algorithm to solve this exact problem.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2287818/339790)

Comment: I don't think you can expect a *formula* for the distance. As pointed out by @angryavian in general an algorithm is needed to compute the projection.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2327504/339790)